# A way to find a word in a text document and delete the line with the word and the following 6 Lines (Python)

Tags: python

Is there a way to open a text file, find a word, delete the line with the word, and the following 6 lines of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have explain logic for `file` editing with various section:

First we open file in `read write mode` because `r+ doesn't overwrite the previously written file`

```
f = open("file.txt", 'r')
content = f.read()
```

---

Then we `split` it into various line

```
lines_ = content.split('\n')[::-1]
word = input('Enter your words : ')
```

---

Apply logic to remove maatch word line and 6 consecutive line.

```
for i, j in zip(range(len(lines_)), lines_):
    if word in j:
        for k in range(7):
            if i > abs(k):
                del lines_[i-k]
file_ = '\n'.join(lines_[::-1])
f.close()
```

---

Again we open file to write that updated string into file back that is why we use `w write mode` which first clear the file then place string into it

```
with open("file.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(file_)
```

Comment: Welcome! I am glad by helping you. Please flow `Stack Overflow` guidelines while questioning.

Comment: I would suggest to use 'r' to open file - we only need to read, writing is not used.  
Also you have suggested `with open()` at the end, that is 'pythonic way' but you did not when opening file to read and the beginning. @ExplooreX

Comment: thanks for that point I will add. But for clear explanation i divide this into section so without any consideration of `fileNotFound Error` or namespace.

Comment: Also when dealing with deleting I would suggest reading lines from the end to the beggining so we do not skip any matches when removing previous match.
Imagin we have 10 lines and magic word is in line 1 and 5 - if we start removing from the start we will remove second magic word and leave more lines

Comment: Thanks for your answer it hasnt worked before but got it now. Thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
def look_and_delete(file,word_to_look_for):
  files = open(file,'r')
  contents = files.readlines()
  print(contents)
  line  = 0
  file_words = ''
  for i in contents:
    print(i)
    if word_to_look_for in i:
      print("im in here on line", line)
    else:
      file_words+=i
    line+=1
  print(file_words)
  files.close()
  files = open(file,'w')
  files.write(file_words)
  files.close()
```

Fell free to remove the print statement they are irrelevant

Comment: Yeah this works if you want to replace or delete 1 line out of a document but i wanted to delete the line with the word + 5 lines.
Thanks for your answer tho!

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it in another way
First open file and read lines for later, `n=5` means - remove 5 lines including line with magic word.

```py
magic_word = 'foo'
n = 5
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file_handle:
    lines = file_handle.readlines()
num_lines = len(lines)
```

Next we enumerate over lines but in reverse. This is very important for a corner case, ex.:
If we take this kind of input:

```
test1
foo
test2
test3
test4
foo
test5
test6
test7
test8
```

Reading file from start to end (let `n=5`) and looking for a magic word will result with output:

```
test1
test5
test6
test7
test8
```

But if we look and remove from the other end the result is:

```
test1
```

That is why we need to revere the order.

> `strip` is just so we can remove `\n` before comparison.

```py
for idx, word in enumerate(reversed(lines)):
    # now going from the end of a file
    word = word.strip()
```

When we find magic word, we have to remove `n` line from this point to file end.  Easiest operation to remove parts of a iterable in python is to slice

> ex. `obj[1:5]` cut objects in range `<1,5>` or `obj[:5]` cut objects in range `<0,5>`

```py
    if word == magic_word:
        left_bound = num_lines-idx-1
        if left_bound + n >= num_lines:
            lines = lines[:left_bound]
        else:
            lines = lines[:left_bound] + lines[left_bound+n:]
```

All that is left is to save the file(override)

```py
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file_handle:
    lines = file_handle.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: You broke my brain with this solutution i dont understand it the way i need to and it also wont work for me.
Still huge thanks to you, because you got me some ideas to try and learn more!

Comment: @Jenby32 if you find it useful, I would appreciate an upvote :)

Comment: Oh yeah, it wasnt the answer i needet but it helped me tho. Thanks! :D